# need to increment a group of results only using multiple loop statements

Tags: php

I have the following php code:

```
    $k=1;
    for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM services_main');
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            if ($row['ID'] == $i) {

                for($j=1; $j <= 3; $j++)
                {
                    echo $row['name'].' - k='.$k++.'<br />';
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

This code generates this:

```
    John - k=1
    John - k=2
    John - k=3
    Paul - k=4
    Paul - k=5
    Paul - k=6
    George - k=7
    George - k=8
    George - k=9
```

What i am trying to do it have it generate this:

```
    John - k=1
    John - k=1
    John - k=1
    Paul - k=2
    Paul - k=2
    Paul - k=2
    George - k=3
    George - k=3
    George - k=3
```

I can't figure out how to make k increment for each grouping as opposed to incrementing on every single line.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `k++` outside the `while` loop.

```
$k=1;
for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM services_main');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        if ($row['ID'] == $i) {

            for($j=1; $j <= 3; $j++)
            {
                echo $row['name'].' - k='.$k.'<br />';
            }

        }
    }
    $k++;
}
```

Comment: thanks Ryan, this works NOTE, i think you meant $k++; instead of k++;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of incrementing $k each time you go through your inner "for" loop, increment it once per iteration of your "while" loop:

```
for($j=1; $j <= 3; $j++)
{
    echo $row['name'].' - k='.$k.'<br />';
}
$k++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
for($j=1; $j <= 3; $j++)
            {
                echo $row['name'].' - k='.$k++.'<br />';
            }
```

With this

```
for($j=1; $j <= 3; $j++)
            {
                echo $row['name'].' - k='.$k.'<br />';
            }
$k++;
```